# AWS SDK for .NET can't access credentials with IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having some trouble accessing the AWS credentials in the SDK Store, but it seems to only be a problem when running under IIS. If I hit the same code by invoking an NUnit test with ReSharper the dependency injection works and the S3 client is able to authenticate.

```
IAmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
```

Has anyone else run into this problem? How were you able to get the dependency injection to work?

[Edit]

The credential file approach has been recommended for use with IIS because the SDK Store encrypts the credentials differently for each user. I can only get a credentials file to work if I hard-code the path in the appSettings which I do not want to do.

Where would the SDK look for the credentials file besides the below paths?

```
C:\Users\<IIS_app_name>\.aws\credentials
C:\Users\<my_domain_user>\.aws\credentials
```

Comment: The SDK will also look for a web.config file in inetpub\wwwroot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question was answered under Pavel's answer, but I'll post an answer to make the information easier to consume. You can specify the credentials file location in the webLocal.config (I wasn't able to get it to work without that). When the app is deployed, the credentials file location will be an invalid path, and the SDK will fail over to using the IAM role for the EC2 instance.

**webLocal.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<appSettings>
    <!-- AWS -->
    <add key="AWSProfilesLocation" value="C:\Users\<IIS_app_name>\.aws\credentials" />
    <add key="AWSRegion" value="us-west-2" />
    <add key="S3Bucket" value="bucket." />
</appSettings>
```

The dependency injection will work when you instantiate a client without arguments.

```
IAmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me -- or maybe I'm using wrong `IIS_app_name`. How do I get the `<IIS_app_name>`? Thanks.

Comment: Note that if you don't want to modify your application's web.config file, these settings can also be added to the machine.config file (default location is C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config).
This is a good solution for local development since the web.config is usually added to  your repository whereas the machine.config is only local.

Answer (score 7):

The SDK Store saves the credentials under the `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\AWSToolkit` folder, so unless IIS is being run under the same account as the NUnit tests, IIS will not be able to access the same credentials.

[This blog](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx1310VG2O81PSY/Referencing-Credentials-using-Profiles) discusses the various options for storing and using credentials. In your case, it looks like a better option would be to use the credentials file.

Comment: I had tried adding a credentials file under the IIS user's folder and hadn't had luck there (C:\Users\<IIS_app_name>\.aws\credentials). Out of curiosity I also tried duplicating the AWSToolkit folder (C:\Users\<IIS_app_name>\AppData\Local\AWSToolkit) for the IIS user and I'm still getting the same error. At this point I'm stumped. I wish I could see which search paths are failing in the error message.

Comment: SDK Store has a different file format than the credentials file: it is JSON and encrypted.
So your first attempt will not work as the SDK Store (under IIS) is looking for JSON files, not aws\credentials.
Your second attempt will not work as the credentials are encrypted differently for each user, so the IIS user cannot decrypt your credentials files.
You need to create the aws\credentials file, then point to it either in code or in config, as illustrated in the blog post I linked.

Comment: Pavel, It makes sense that the SDK store option won't work if the credentials are encrypted differently for each user so I'm glad to know that. I've only been able to get the credentials file to work if I hard code the path in the webLocal.config. Using `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.aws\credentials` in the AWSProfilesLocation app setting isn't working for me. I've got credential files in my user folder and the IIS app user folder. Where else could it be searching for the credential file besides `C:\Users\<IIS_app_name>\.aws\credentials` if I don't specify the path?

Comment: Would specifying a credential file location prevent the use of IAM roles for authentication when deployed to EC2?

Comment: If a profiles location is specified, the SDK will only look in that location (if no profile name is specified, SDK looks for profile named "default"). Otherwise, the SDK looks for the SDK Store. Unfortunately, the current version of the SDK does not expand environment variables, so you would need to use an absolute path.

Comment: If you've specified a profile location but on an EC2 instance this doesn't resolve to valid credentials, the SDK will attempt to use the EC2 Instance Profile credentials. So a possible approach here would be to test locally with a hard-coded path, then deploy to EC2 with an instance profile, where the SDK will pick up the instance credentials instead.